# Getting config information from a MediaWiki page

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am developing a MediaWiki extension and I would like it to be able to pull simple configuration settings from a MediaWiki page that can be edited when and if certain things are added such as a category. I am quite unsure how I would go about doing something like this. any help would be appreciated/

Comment: I think you need to be more specific if you want to get a proper answer here. Try to describe what you want to do in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, on-wiki settings would be stored in the MediaWiki namespace. There are no built in methods for getting and setting such configuration setting, so you will have to parse those pages manually. For a (quite complex) example, see how the sidebar is built from `MediaWiki:Sidebar` in **[Skin.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/master/includes/Skin.php)**

A more user friendly approach, of course, would be to create a simple special page, that gets and sets the configuration settings from the database. Depending on your exact needs, that might be almost as simple to build.